# How to implement a change method in Android ViewModel

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I'm studying the [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/GithubBrowserSample) source and I see that it has only queries/get methods, I mean, it only request data and does not do any update/change/post to the rest api.

For example, [UserViewModel.kt](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/user/UserViewModel.kt) has the code below:

```
val user: LiveData<Resource<User>> = _login.switchMap { login ->
    if (login == null) {
        AbsentLiveData.create()
    } else {
        userRepository.loadUser(login)
    }
}

fun setLogin(login: String?) {
    if (_login.value != login) {
        _login.value = login
    }
}
```

So basically, I call `setLogin` and the `user` `LiveData` will call `userRepository.loadUser(login)` if there's an observer, this looks good to me and no questions here. However, how would I implement something like UpdateUserProfile?

If I follow the same pattern, I would create a method like `fun updateUserProfile(userProfile: userProfile)` and this method would set the `userProfile` to a `LiveData` and then I would need to have an observer observing that `LiveData` in order to have `userRepository` to call `updateUserProfile`.

But it doesn't make sense to me.

So what's the best/recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your data exactly is and what you're trying to show:

1. If your `UserProfile` is not something that you show on the UI, then you could just call the network request and update the `user` livedata with the new information. (You can do this with multiple options, happy heuristic - update before request finishes & reset on error, or just update the `user` when request finishes)
2. If you show the `UserProfile` separately from the `user` information, then you probably would create a `LiveData/Observable` for it and update accordingly when the request finishes.

**TL;DR** I wouldn't follow the same pattern here, since I don't think it applies:
In the first case probably `login` is shown separately from the `UI` and they implemented a reactive pattern to listening to these changes and fetching the user information. In your case you don't have `login` + `user`, you just have `userProfile`